# Is there a single word for "similar things/phenomena"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I wonder if there's a single word that one can use for phrases, such as:

- "similar things"
- "similar phenomena"
- "similar concepts"
- "related things"
- "associated things"

etc.

I first thought of **relate**, but it looks like it's a technical term of logic and can only be used for things or phenomena that are involved in a specific logical relation.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a sample sentence with a ___ in place of the single word you're looking for. It's not clear what part of speech you need and how you want to use the word. I've added an answer for cases where you want noun  for "... and similar/related things/concepts/etc." after stated examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you might be looking for is.

#### alike

**alike**'s definition is:

> *adjective*
>
> (of two or more people or things) similar to each other.

Example sentences with **alike**.

Instead of:

> John and Bob look similar to each other.

Say:

> John and Bob look alike.

---

Instead of:

> Residents and tourists take advantage in a similar way of the boating, scuba diving and fishing opportunities.

Say:

> Residents and tourists alike take advantage of the boating, scuba diving and fishing opportunities.

Comment: _Alike_ has some syntactic peculiarities; for one thing, it can't precede the nouns it modifies. *_Alike residents and tourists take advantage_ It's also used in a lot of idioms like _share and share alike_.

Answer (score 0):

> **Like (n.)**
>
> **and the like**
>
> Used at the end of a list to indicate that further, similar items are
> included; and so on, and so forth, et cetera. Similarly **or the
> like**.
>
> 1833   S. Austin *Characteristics Goethe* I. ii. 30   Questions
> concerning time, space, mind, matter, God, immortality, **and the like**.
>
> 2012   *Guardian* 17 Aug. 34/5   Happily, we are no longer permitted
> to discriminate against gender, sexuality, race, religion, disability
> **and the like**. OED

---

> As a means of transport, a bicycle differs from a train, plane, car,
> **and the like** in requiring personal effort on the driver's part, thereby affirming his or her will, directive, acumen, and energy.
> [Bettina Knapp; *Machine, Metaphor, and the Writer*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Machine_Metaphor_and_the_Writer_A_Jungia/ekrHJ2vgr7cC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22and%20the%20like%22&pg=PA19&printsec=frontcover) (1989)

> Consequently the modified multiethnics are burdened with problems of
> various sorts: quarrels, party strife, poverty, irresponsibility,
> infidelity, **and the like**.
> [Donald McGavran; *Ethnic Realities and the Church*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ethnic_Realities_and_the_Church/XCaLJq3ADQgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22and%20the%20like%22&pg=PA147&printsec=frontcover) (1979)

> The increased speed of warships, and the much longer ranges at which
> large-calibre guns could throw their shells, posed an enormous
> challenge to gunnery officers everywhere, and a vast amount of thought
> was given to developing new range-finders, spotting devices,
> calibration techniques **and the like**.
> [J. Hattendorf and R.
> Jordand; *Maritime Strategy and the Balance of Power*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Maritime_Strategy_And_The_Balance_Of_Pow/jd-uCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22and%20the%20like%22&pg=PA170&printsec=frontcover) (1989)

> A tampion, or wad, of oakum **or the like**, was rammed down between
> the cartridge and the ball, and a second wad kept the ball in place.
> [John Masefield; *On the Spanish Main*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/On_the_Spanish_Main_Or_Some_English_fora/TciIEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22or%20the%20like%22&pg=PT244&printsec=frontcover) (2022)